# Confused about uniqueness of eigenspaces when computing from eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am kind of confused.  For a specific eigenvalue, I found the eigenspace could be either $\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$ or

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\-1\end{bmatrix}$ by computing the $kernel(A-\lambda I)$.  These two values are basically the same, right?  If I use either eigenspace as the basis for $S$ and $S^{-1}$, it should give equivalent answers, right?

Also, under what circumstances (if any) are there more than one eigenspaces per eigenvalue in an $n \times n$ matrix.  If the dimension of the kernel is greater than one, there should be more than one eigenspace for that particular eigenvalue right?

Thanks for the clarifications, I hope this makes sense.

Comment: you mean that the eigenspace is $\operatorname{span}[(-1,0,1)]$? The notation is far to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some given eigenvalue, there are many eigen*vectors* of a matrix. The eigen*space* is the set of *all* the eigenvectors, so there's only one eigen*space*.

In your example, (1,0,-1) and (-1,0,1) are eigenvectors - but so are (5,0,-5), (-1729$\pi$,0,1729$\pi$) and so on.

There's only one eigen*space*, namely, $\{(t,0,-t)|t\in F\}$ where $F$ is the field your vectors are over.